# Teradata REGEX or SUBSTR to remove the text between two *'s and the asterisk?

Tags: regex, teradata, substr, teradata-sql-assistant

I'm working in teradata with a dataset that has several occurrences of data in the following format:

```
*6A*H.ORTHO I
*4A*IMP
*16A*T.IMPLANTS
*2A*HIMPLANTS
*9A*IMP
*5A*F.IMPLANT
*6A*DIMP
*4A*TISSUE
*5A*KIMP
*7A*IMP
*10A*D.IMP
*3A*W.LSH
*10A*IMP
*16A*IMP
*22A*T.IMPLANTS
```

In the dataset above I'm attempting to extract everything after the second occurrence of an asterick.  I.E. D.IMP, IMP, T.IMPLANTS, F.IMPLANT, etc..

I've attempted to use SUBSTR and came close using:

```
SUBSTR(TRIM(FSS.Surgical_Inventory_Code),1,
                    INDEX(TRIM(FSS.Surgical_Inventory_Code),'*')-1)
```

But, that only returns the data after the first *.

I believe the best solution to solve problem would be using a REGEX expression or SUBSTR.  There is a function in teradata called REGEXP_SUBSTR.  I'm not exactly sure how to create a REGEX statement to solve my problem.

Comment: `instr` can be used to find the 2nd occurance: `substring(FSS.Surgical_Inventory_Code from instr(FSS.Surgical_Inventory_Code, '*', 2)+1)`

Comment: Thank you for this.  I'd like to mark this answer correct as well as the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only ever have 2 asterisks in your string, you can use STRTOK:

```
strtok(<source string>,'*',2)
```